# Problem creating dynamic index from filename (filebeat)

Tags: logstash, filebeat

i am trying to create index name same as filename from source but it doesn't seem to work, here's my logstash config file :

```
input {
  beats{
 port=> 5044
 }
}

 filter {
 grok {
      match => ["source",".*\\%{GREEDYDATA:app_name}"]
   }
}
  output {
    stdout {
     codec => rubydebug
      }
     elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     index => "%{app_name}"
   }
 }
```

logs sample :

07:52:29.040 [ORB.thread.pool : 0][INFO ] ServiceArriereGuichet    - @PostConstruct ServiceArriereGuichet
2020-02-17 08:05:33 INFO  certification - Traitement Flux XML
2020-02-18 08:27:08,603 INFO info : Fin de construction du flux de sortie.

pattern test:

[image]

Comment: What is the error? How are your log messages? Update your question with a sample of your messages. Also, this `".*\\%{GREEDYDATA:app_name}"` does not seems to be correct, what are you trying to parse?

Comment: i tested this pattern and it works in a grok debbuger, i've provided the log examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, i have used [log][file][path] instead of source and i used mutate to transform it to lowercase, now it's creating indexes based on the source filename.

thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I think most probably issue might be

1. with your source data
2. pattern that you are using

Probably use this [herokuapp tool](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to test your grok pattern, whether you are getting the expected result or not based on source data.

Rule out the issue is not with the Grok pattern by giving a fixed index name and test the value of app_name in Elasticsearch indexed data.

Irrespective of the Grok pattern issue, I would recommend not to use the extracted value as it is unless you have total control on the source data. Instead, provide a default index name incase grok pattern fails using [Logstash conditional statements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals).

Comment: i used other fields that 100% exist and it still doesn't work!